# mismatch between sos and clr versions - how to resolve

Tags: .net-4.0, sos, windb

After loading dump file in windbg, I ran following command

> .loadby sos clr

Bu then I got following message when running ThreadPool command

```
> 0:000> !ThreadPool The version of SOS does not match the version of
> CLR you are debugging.  Please load the matching version of SOS for
> the version of CLR you are debugging. CLR Version: 4.0.30319.18444 SOS
> Version: 4.0.30319.34011
```

Am I doing something wrong? I have .NET 4.5 installed on machine where I am doing analysis. If I try to install .NET 4.0 on that machine, it doesn't let me because a higher version is already installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to do with "The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging" in WinDbg?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430769/what-to-do-with-the-version-of-sos-does-not-match-the-version-of-clr-you-are-de)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, you need to match SOS version to all 4 version places of the CLR and the DAC (mscordacwks.dll).  However, these are both .NET 4.5 versions, so you should be safe to ignore this warning.  In order to resolve it, you need to get SOS.dll from the installation where the dump was taken.